# Query string in form action when mixing POST and GET?

Tags: php, post, get, action

So I have a profile page: `profile.php?pin=xx`, where I use the GET method for determining which profile to display. I am going to test if `$_SESSION['pin'] == $_GET['pin']` and if so, give the option to edit profile.

I don't want to write a-whole-nother script and direct the user to another page. So for usability sake, and keeping the server neat so I'm not always guessing which script does what, I want to mix POST and GET. I've done some research and it seems legal, but how?

```
<form method="post" action="profile.php?pin=xx">
<form method="post" action="<? echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
```

That's all I can think of without really getting the code messy.

Comment: Use $_REQUEST which contains POST and GET both values

Comment: No, don't use `$_REQUEST` - you want to be _explicit_ about where each value comes from. It also contains `$_COOKIE`.

Comment: Did you try what you have above? It will work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you keep the action attribute empty it will be the same URI including the GET parameters (query-info part of the URI):

```
<form method="post" action="">
```

Maybe this  is what you're looking for? See [HTML `<form>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/form) for a reference about tag and attribute.

If you want to understand how that works: This is a so called *Relative URI*. It resolves to the *Base URI* of the document. As the *Relative URI* is empty, the *Base URI* is being taken over completely.